# Binding C++ to QML code when using Components

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, binding, qml

---edited url and changed dynamic part to something compilable----
(Using Qt 5.3)
I tried to create a compact sample, but its still too big to post all the files here separately, so i added a link to "uploaded.to" as i cannot seem to attach a zip file here :-((
(warning, spam links and / or waiting time, any better fileshare site you recommend ?

Here is a link to "bindtest.zip" via uploaded.com, beware of spam/ugly pix:

http://ul.to/lqemy5jx

Okay, i will try to post the essence of the files here anyways:

I tried to create a simple Class in C++ containing a StringList and an index.
I Instantiated two Objects of this Class and exposed them via "setContextProperty"

This should be used in QML to initialize a ListView and to be in sync with it.
So whenever a User changes the index in QML, C++ should be notified AND vice versa.

So when i create two Component qml files using the hardwired names set in "setContextProperty" it seems to work fine.

But for the life of me i cannot create a single component file and pass the DataObject to it as a parameter, i simply do not know how to do it, although i tried.

My "final" target ist to create a QML Object dynamically and pass the DataObject to it, this does not work either :-(

So here it comes, code snippets of my sample Project:

Declaring my oh-so-simple Class (DataObject.h)

```
#ifndef DATAOBJECT_H
#define DATAOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class DataObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( int index MEMBER m_index NOTIFY indexChanged )
public slots:
    int count() const { return m_Elements.count(); }
    QString at(int idx) const { return m_Elements.at(idx); }
public:
    void setIndex(int theInt) { m_index = theInt; }
signals:
    void indexChanged(int);
public: // too lazy to write accessors for this sample, so make it public
    QStringList m_Elements;
private:
    int m_index;
};
#endif // DATAOBJECT_H
```

Registering it in main.cpp:

```
qmlRegisterType<DataObject>("bindtestTypes", 1, 0, "DataObject");
```

Here is the part of "dialog.cpp" that initializes and exposes two DataObects:

```
//preparing first list
m_firstDO.m_Elements = QStringList() << "A" << "B" << "C" << "D";
m_firstDO.setIndex(0);

//preparing second list
m_secondDO.m_Elements = QStringList() << "a" << "b" << "c" << "d";
m_secondDO.setIndex(3);

//publish the 2 Dataobjects
m_engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "cppDataList_1", &m_firstDO);
m_engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty( "cppDataList_2", &m_secondDO);
```

Here is the QML file "ShowLists.qml" that should simply show the 2 ListVies on Top of each other, i commented the 2 NOT working approaches that i would love to work, especially the dynamic one:

import QtQuick 2.2
    import QtQuick.Window 2.1
    import bindtestTypes 1.0

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 200
    height: 400
    Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: parent
//dynamic: does not work :-(
// need to click on it to create it
//        Rectangle{
//            id:upperList
//            anchors.top: parent.top;
//            anchors.left: parent.left
//            width:200
//            height:200
//            MouseArea{
//                anchors.fill: parent
//                onClicked: {
//                    var component = Qt.createComponent("SimpleList.qml");
//                    var dyncbb = component.createObject(parent, {"theDO": cppDataList_1});
//                }
//            }

//        }
//        Rectangle{
//            id:lowerList
//            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
//            anchors.left: parent.left
//            width:200
//            height:200
//            MouseArea{
//                anchors.fill: parent
//                onClicked: {
//                    var component = Qt.createComponent("SimpleList.qml");
//                    var dyncbb = component.createObject(parent, {"theDO": cppDataList_2});
//                }
//            }
//        }


//static: would not be my first choice but isnt working anyways...
//        SimpleList {
//            id:upperList
//            property DataObject theDO: cppDataList_1
//            anchors.top: parent.top;
//            anchors.left: parent.left
//        }
//        SimpleList {
//            id:lowerList
//            property DataObject theDO: cppDataList_2
//            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
//            anchors.left: parent.left
//        }

//hardwired works, but its not workable for my rather complex project...
        SimpleList1 {
            id:upperList
            anchors.top: parent.top;
            anchors.left: parent.left
        }
        SimpleList2 {
            id:lowerList
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom;
            anchors.left: parent.left
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the first hardwired SimpleList1.qml that works fine, as well as the second:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

    ListView {
        id: list_view
        width: 200
        height: 200

        currentIndex: cppDataList_1.index
        model: cppDataList_1.count()

        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 20
            width: 200
            Text { text: cppDataList_1.at(index); color: (list_view.currentIndex === index)?"red":"black" }
            MouseArea{ anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: list_view.currentIndex = index }
        }
        onCurrentIndexChanged: cppDataList_1.index = currentIndex;
    }
```

This is the "SimpleList.qml" that i cannot seem to get to work:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import bindtestTypes 1.0

Rectangle {
    ListView {
        id: list_view
        property DataObject theDO
        width: 200
        height: 200

        currentIndex: theDO.index
        model: theDO.count()

        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 20
            width: 200
            Text { text: theDO.at(index); color: (list_view.currentIndex === index)?"red":"black" }
            MouseArea{ anchors.fill: parent; onClicked: list_view.currentIndex = index }
        }
        onCurrentIndexChanged: theDO.index = currentIndex
    }
}
```

So, can anyone of you help me to get this solved ??

IF you dare to follow the uploaded link and run my sample you can see one more glitch.
It displays 2 Windows, one QQQuickWIndow and a Widget.
In the Widget i can change the indexes as well as in the QML Window.
At first they are in sync but then the QML Window does not get updated anymore by changing the index in the widget, i hope its a glitch and not another general error i made.

Greetings & thanks for any help !

Nils

Comment: I think you're getting a lot of downvotes because the question is way too big/complex. You need to first put the effort into narrowing it down into the smallest amount of code that reproduces the problem, so that we can try it out ourselves without having to download and search through your entire project.

Comment: Hi ! I wondered about the down votes, thanks for the possible explanation.If no one "dares" to help i will try to rephrase in simpler & smaller parts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Argh, i found the problem, i did a very simple mistake:

The property i want to set in the SimpleList Component has to be in the root Object, so instead of this:

```
Rectangle {
    ListView {
        id: list_view
        property DataObject theDO
...
```

It has to be done this way:

```
Rectangle {
    property DataObject theDO
    ListView {
        id: list_view
...
```

Wow, thats an easy solution for a (seemingly) complex Problem.

Greetings,

Nils